# gatttool Function not implemented error

Tags: bluetooth

I am using ubuntu 16.04 and I have a BLE peripheral device that I am trying to connect to, however gatttools fails to connect and produces an error:

```
    [                 ][LE]> connect F1:F8:F2:CB:77:3A
Attempting to connect to F1:F8:F2:CB:77:3A
Error: connect error: Function not implemented (38)
```

dmesg logs:

```
[10697.903518] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
```

One in a hundred tries I manage to connect for a split second, but the immediately get invalid descriptor error. I have tried connecting through bluetoothctl but no luck as well. Connecting to other peripherals works.

Any advice is welcome, thank you.

Comment: Figured it out.  Turns out the device doesn't accept connections and only transmits advertisement data to save power which is the whole point of bluetooth low energy.